# How to use cache when constructor is called

Tags: c#

I have a class `MyClass` and since it takes some time to create an instance of this class, I want to use cache. My idea was to create the following constructor:

```
public MyClass(string name, int value)
    {
        if (Cache.MyClassObjects.ContainsKey(name))
            this = Cache.MyClassObjects[name]
        else:
            this.Name = name;
            this.Value = value;
    }
```

The problem is that I can't perform this line `this = Cache.MyClassObjects[name]`. For me the above is the most natural solution - user called the constructor and if the object with the same name and value already exsists - return that object. Another solution would be to implement a static function inside my class but first I would like to know why this doesnt work.

Comment: I don't believe there is enough code to determine why the cache doesn't work. 
But under the assumption: 

private static Cache _cache = new Cache(); Is in your field area of My Class, then the constructor should work just fine.

and your code:

public MyClass(string name, int value)
    {
        if (_cache.MyClassObjects.ContainsKey(name))
            this = _Cache.MyClassObjects[name]
        else:
            this.Name = name;
            this.Value = value;
    }

You need the field to be static, so that all objects share the same field. Then your code makes sense.

Comment: If you're using a constructor to instantiate MyClass, you're already creating a new instance. Assigning `this` will not help. 
In your case you might want to look into the Factory pattern, letting the factory create only new instances when it's necessary.

Comment: @MortenBork No it doesn't. This kind of logic belongs in a Factory, not in a CTOR. A CTOR cannot do this kind of thing. Not even mentioning the incorrect syntax of the `if/else`.

Comment: If you implement a dependency injection and lifetime management framework in your application you'll find a natural place to cache the instantiation of objects
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor always returns new instance by design. Runtime allocates memory for that fresh instance (for reference types at least), and then your constructor runs. Then fresh instance is returned to the caller.

It can't allow you to return completely separate existing instance and throw away the fresh one it already allocated memory for. Well with some efforts language designers might have been able to implement that syntax, but there is absolutely no reason to waste time on that - you already know how to do it with the current version of the language, just use static method.